# step progress bar with android compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Currently I'm trying to find an easy way to implement a step progress bar with compose like this:

[image]

Does anyone have experience with that? Is there maybe a good library?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you need a library from this one, a simple and quick 'do it yourself' solution could be something like this:

```
@Composable
fun StepsProgressBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, numberOfSteps: Int, currentStep: Int) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        for (step in 0..numberOfSteps) {
            Step(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1F),
                isCompete = step < currentStep,
                isCurrent = step == currentStep
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Step(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, isCompete: Boolean, isCurrent: Boolean) {
    val color = if (isCompete || isCurrent) Color.Red else Color.LightGray
    val innerCircleColor = if (isCompete) Color.Red else Color.LightGray

    Box(modifier = modifier) {

        //Line
        Divider(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart),
            color = color,
            thickness = 2.dp
        )

        //Circle
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier
            .size(15.dp)
            .align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
            .border(
                shape = CircleShape,
                width = 2.dp,
                color = color
            ),
            onDraw = {
                drawCircle(color = innerCircleColor)
            }
        )
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun StepsProgressBarPreview() {
    val currentStep = remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    StepsProgressBar(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), numberOfSteps = 5, currentStep = currentStep.value)
}
```

This will be the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your idea.. Thats very neat

Comment: How can I use this step progressBar as a vertical progressBar?

Comment: how can I remove the Divider at first?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a similar function that takes customisable params.

```
@Composable
fun Track(
    items: Int,
    brush: (from: Int) -> Brush,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    lineWidth: Dp = 1.dp,
    pathEffect: ((from: Int) -> PathEffect?)? = null,
    icon: @Composable (index: Int) -> Unit,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .zIndex(-1f)
        ) {
            val width = drawContext.size.width
            val height = drawContext.size.height

            val yOffset = height / 2
            val itemWidth = width / items

            var startOffset = itemWidth / 2
            var endOffset = startOffset

            val barWidth = lineWidth.toPx()
            repeat(items - 1) {
                endOffset += itemWidth
                drawLine(
                    brush = brush.invoke(it),
                    start = Offset(startOffset, yOffset),
                    end = Offset(endOffset, yOffset),
                    strokeWidth = barWidth,
                    pathEffect = pathEffect?.invoke(it)
                )
                startOffset = endOffset
            }
        }

        Row(
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        ) {
            repeat(items) { index ->
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                ) {
                    icon.invoke(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: how to call the composable function? like how to pass the parameters in the lamdas to get something like 'Track Preview 3'? and I can't figure out how to pass the progress too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add jitpack in your build.gradle:

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
       ...
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Add [compose-stepper](https://github.com/maryamrzdh/compose-stepper) library to your app/build.gradle

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation 'com.github.maryamrzdh:compose-stepper:1.0.0-beta01'
   }
   ```

Add a **Stepper** in a composable function

```
        @Composable
        fun StepperView() {

            val numberOfSteps = 4
            var currentStep by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(1) }
            val titleList= arrayListOf("Step 1","Step 2","Step 3","Step 4")

             Stepper(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                numberOfSteps = numberOfSteps,
                currentStep = currentStep,
                stepDescriptionList = titleList,
                unSelectedColor= Color.LightGray,
                selectedColor = Color.Blue,
                isRainbow = false
         )
```

For more info go to [Stepper using JetPack Compose](https://medium.com/@maryamemarzadeh72/stepper-using-jetpack-compose-3765bce0f1b3)